# Capturing shift key state on Windows 8 tablet in MFC App

Tags: windows, windows-8, mfc

Our MFC-based Windows application has functionality that depends on the state of the shift key.  Shift exposes power-user menu commands and shift-dragging has different behavior than normal dragging.  I am exploring our options in supporting Windows 8 tablets, and it seems that there is no straightforward way to detect the state of the  Windows 8 soft keypad shift key.

Using `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)` (our current method) doesn't detect this key.

Experimenting with examining all incoming keyboard messages, I find:

- A single isolated tap of the shift key produces no keyboard event
- A double tap of the shift key produces a caps lock key event, indistinguishable from a normal caps lock key event
- A single tap of the shift key followed by another keystroke (eg. the 'q' key) produces a shift key event, the keystroke, and a shift key (up?) event.

Are there any other ways I could try to detect the state of the soft keyboard shift key?  Has anyone else had success detecting the state of this keypad on Windows 8 tablet soft keyboards.

The external keyboards that you plug into these devices all have normal behaving shift keys.  The problem is specific to the soft keypad.

Comment: Calling `GetAsynKeyState` returns the interrupt-level state associated with the hardware. This might explain why it doesn't return the expected result when used with the soft keyboard. In contrast calling [`GetKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx) (when handling keyboard messages) or evaluating the `wParam` (when handling for example [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607.aspx)) should work for both the soft keyboard as well as an external keyboard.